# Remove repetitive template markup for Angular 2 components

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am working on an Angular 2 project that is built on the [Gentallela Alela!](https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/index.html) html template. Most of my views have a couple of components that all have the following markup in their template file:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="x_panel">
    <div class="x_title">

      <h2> **Name of component** </h2>

      <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
        <li myToggleContentPanel><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li myCloseContentPanel><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="x_content">


    **Actual content of my component**


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This obviously results in quite an amount of repeated code. That isn't desirable. I was wondering what would be a good way to solve this issue. In projects with the python framework Django I was able to import pieces of template inside template files as follows:

```
<div class="basic">
{% include "main/includes/subtemplate.html" %}    
</div>
```

Is something like that also possible in Angular 2? Or do you recommend another approach?

I made an image to clarify it all a bit up:

[image]

The main problem is that I don't have a pre defined number of components, so as far as I know this couldn't work with aux routers?

Comment: routers are made for it :)

Comment: I added an update to clarify it a bit up, is this still possible with routers if I have a dynamic number of components?

Comment: Build a reusable component containing the repeating markup and add the component wherever needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to read through the Angular 2+ docs as this is exactly what Angular is good at.

Your components (of which you say there are not a set number) are actually just the same reusable component with different values for certain inputs.

I would suggest you define a reusable component with all of your re-usable markup in it's template. Like..

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { StuffService } from './stuff.service';
import { Stuff } from './stuff.model';

// This is your reusable component (a dumb component). 
// This can be used wherever you like in your app.

@Component({
    selector: 'app-reusable',
    template: `
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="x_panel">
                    <div class="x_title">

                    <h2> {{name}} </h2>

                    <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                        <li myToggleContentPanel><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li myCloseContentPanel><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="x_content">
                            <ng-content></ng-content>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    `})
export class ReusableComponent {
    @Input() public name: string;
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------


// Below is your main component. ( A smart component - uses services to get data) 
// This is what your router hooks up to.

@Component({
    template: `
            <h2>
                Below are all my components!
            </h2>
            <p> There is one for each item in the arrayOfStuff! (using the *ngFor directive </p>
            <p> The input variables can be passed in using the [varible]="whateverYouArePassingIn" syntax like the stuff.name is passed in</p>
            <p> The stuff you put in between your reusable componet tags replaces the ng-content tags. 
                This is usefull if you want to put specific markup in a specific instance of a reusable component. 
                (This was called transclusion in Angular 1.)
            </p>

            <app-reusable *ngFor="let stuff of arrayOfStuff" [name]="stuff.name">
                **All of this stuff replaces the ng-content tags in the Reusable Component**
            </app-reusable>
     `
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
    public arrayOfStuff: Stuff[];

    public constructor(private stuffService: StuffService) { }

    public ngOnInit() {
        this.arrayOfStuff = this.stuffService.getStuff;
    }

}
```

This is only using the fundamental principles of the framework. So I strongly urge you to read through the [Angular intro docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/learning-angular.html).

Comment: Thanks for your extensive example! I will also give the docs a look!